# Are there any unforeseen side effects within this macro defined messaging, logging, error handling system?

Tags: c++, logging, error-handling, macros, c++17

So far the following source code compiles and runs and is behaving as I intended it to. It is logging the correct messages to the console, it is throwing exceptions and halting executing based on the `MsgTy`, it is writing to a text file if the flag is true. If a file doesn't exist it is creating one, if it already exists, it just appends to it. It appears to be working so far.

I know I could have chosen other ways to create a logging, error-handling, messaging system, but this was an exercise to refresh my skills at writing solid macros. I know they are harder to debug, and I've tried testing all cases and it seems to be okay... I would just like to know if there is anything that I might be missing. This isn't production code, it is for a personal project, but I would like for it to be critiqued as if it was production code.

```
#include <exception>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

enum MsgTy {
    OK = 0,
    WARNING,
    ERROR,
    CRITICAL,
};

static std::map<MsgTy, std::string> msg_id{
    {MsgTy::OK, {"OK: "}},
    {MsgTy::WARNING, {"WARNING: "}},  
    {MsgTy::ERROR, {"ERROR: "}},
    {MsgTy::CRITICAL, {"CRITICAL: "}}
};

class FileWriter {
    std::string filename_;
    std::ostringstream msg_;
public:
    FileWriter(const std::string& filename, std::ostringstream& msg) 
      : filename_{ filename } {
        operator()(msg);
    }

    void operator()(std::ostringstream& msg) {
        std::ofstream out("log.txt", std::ios::app);
        out << msg.str();        
    }
};

#define messaging(MsgTy, msg, log2file) do { \
    std::ostringstream strm; \
    if ((MsgTy) == OK) { \
        strm << msg_id[(MsgTy)] << (msg) << '\n'; \
        std::cout << strm.str(); \
        if((log2file) == true) \
            FileWriter fw("log.txt", strm); \
    } \
    if ((MsgTy) == WARNING) { \
        strm << msg_id[(MsgTy)] << (msg) << '\n'; \
        std::cout << strm.str(); \
        if((log2file) == true) \
            FileWriter fw("log.txt", strm);\
    } \
    if ((MsgTy) == ERROR) { \
        strm << msg_id[(MsgTy)] << (msg) << '\n'; \
        std::cerr << strm.str(); \
        if((log2file) == true) \
            FileWriter fw("log.txt", strm); \
        throw strm.str(); \
    } \
    if ((MsgTy) == CRITICAL) { \
        strm << msg_id[(MsgTy)] << (msg) << '\n'; \
        std::cerr << strm.str(); \
        if((log2file) == true) \
            FileWriter fw("log.txt", strm); \
        throw strm.str(); \
    } \
} while(0)

int main() {
    try {            
        messaging(MsgTy::OK, "Everything is good!", true);
        messaging(MsgTy::WARNING, "Something isn't quite right!", false);
        messaging(MsgTy::ERROR, "Something went wrong!", true);
        messaging(MsgTy::CRITICAL, "Something horribly went wrong!", true);           
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: After looking at the macro for a while, I could write a simple stand-alone helper function to reduce code duplication and then use that in my macro... I'll go ahead and write that now, then maybe update this question to reflect the changes... Then again if I write that function, there is no need for the macro... and this is an exercise specifically for writing marcos!

Comment: Why don't you post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? PS: I didn't downvoted. Just adding it as a suggestion. It should belong there not on SO.

Comment: @brc-dd I wasn't sure which of the two sites were appropriate for this type of question... truth be told, I did post the code there, but the questioning is different. On Code Review, I was asking if any improvements could be made and other feedback. Here, I'm asking if there are any unforeseen side effects or bugs. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/245653/130733